# Benefits option 4 (hosting DNS records) SAP configuration Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

What are the benefits of choosing for the advanced option of hosting all the DNS records of a domain or subdomain for the SAP configuration? The only thing mentioned that it is more advanced and not recommended.

FYI: I only have a basic understanding of the working of DNS e.t.c. And only  used option 2 and 3 (using (sub)domain delgation with NS records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can come up with  single advantage and a few disadvantages. The advantage is the option of using a domain for multiple purposes - e.g. if you want to send from example.com instead of campaign.example.com

You will have a number of existing DNS records, which you will want to keep, like an A record for your website, MX record for your Exchange server. In this case delegating entire example.com will not be possible.

Normally, I would not recommend self hosting, as it is complex and trying to pick and choose which DNS entries to make/adjust could break the DNS authentication or functionality within the application. In addition, each Marketing Cloud client is likely to be using a different domain host/registrar, so there’s never going to be specific instructions Salesforce can provide you on how to configure your domain for use on multiple platforms.

As a result, little or no support can be provided by Salesforce for configuring DNS records when choosing to self-host.

There could be a need for changes to be made to the DNS entries. If Salesforce adds or changes something in their end, the self-hosted DNS entries will need to be updated.